# Why is my spring boot controller not auto-wiring the Validator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-validator

I have a controller with the following:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.Validator;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    //..elided...

    @GetMapping
    public String getSomething(@Valid @RequestBody MyRequest) {

        //This is null
        if ( validator == null ) {
            throw new Exception("is null");
        }
    }
}
```

My configuration class:

```
package com.app.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.app")
public class ValidationConfig {

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {

        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    /* //Including this doesn't help
    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());
        return methodValidationPostProcessor;
    }*/
}
```

Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "1.5.6.RELEASE"
    }
        repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "jacoco"

jar {
    baseName = "my-service"
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    //Spring Boot
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

    //Testing
    testCompile("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

No matter what I do, the validator in my controller is null!

Comment: What is bootstrapping this code?  Seeing that might provide further insight.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild What do you mean? I'm running it with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestMyController {`.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Thank you! You helped me discover the issue. I was using `@InjectMocks private MyController controller` and that left the `@Autowired` fields in it null. Changing to `@Autowired @InjectMocks private MyController controller` fixed it! If you add this as the answer (along with your comment), I'll mark it answered

Comment: My question was regarding what 'kicks this off'?  It looks like it is a JUnit test based on your last comment, but it isn't clear to me what configures your `ApplicationContext`.  I am unfamiliar with `@SpringBootTest` though, so that might be doing it...

Comment: Eh, I would suggest that there is not enough information in the question to have it answered with that...further, I didn't really give that answer...you did!  I would think you could edit your question with your test class code and provide the answer yourself though (which is totally acceptable in StackOverflow)

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you are expecting a `javax.validation.Validator` but in the config you are using `org.springframework.validation.Validator`

Comment: It's still null even after fixing that. (I made both be the spring version)

Comment: Your controller doesn't have a "package" statement at the top, and the code wouldn't even compile, since you're throwing Exception without declaring it. Could you paste the full real code including the main class?